# how to run a double loop with conditional iteration w.r.t group variable in R

Tags: r, loops, datatable

Below is an example of my data:

```
C1 = c("a","a","a","b","b","b","b","c","c")

C2 = c("01-02-2010","01-05-2010","01-08-2010", "02-03-2008","03-04-2009","06-09-2011","09-05-2012", "05-06-2006","06-07-2009")

C3 = c(1,4,3,5,6,7,4,4,7)

C4 = c(3,4,5,6,2,3,4,5,6)

test_dt = data.table::data.table(C1,C2,C3,C4)

colnames(test_dt) = c("variable","date","value1","value2")

unique_variable = unique(C1)
```

Now, I want to run a double loop for both value and date as specified below:

```
LM = NULL

for (j in 1:length(unique_variable)){
  for (i in 1:nrow(test_dt)) {
    print(i)
    print(j)
    LM[[i]] = lm(C3 ~ C4, data =   test_dt[date %between% c(as.Date(test_dt$date[i]) + 1, as.Date(test_dt$date[i]) + 2) & CUSIP == CUSIP_unique[j]])
  }
}
```

When I run the above, it will run all `i` for all `j` (i.e. all 9 values for each of a, b and c)

However, I want it to run in a way that only first 3 for the variable "a", next 4 for variable "b" and last 2 for variable "c" (for each variable it should run for each subset of date as specified too, thus for each variable , eg "a", there would be multiple iterations as per date filter).

Can someone please help.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, what is the format of your variable `date`? "month-date-year" or "date-month-year"?

Comment: hi , its "date-month-year", all variables are arranged date wise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(data.table)
test_dt[, .(model = .(lm(value1 ~ value2, data = .SD))), by = "variable"][["model"]]
```

**Update**

```
library(data.table)
test_dt[, date := as.Date(date, "%d-%m-%Y")]
run_lm <- function(fml, data) {
  if (nrow(data) < 1L) {
    return(NULL)
  }
  lm(fml, data)
}
# between date i + 1 to date i + 5
test_dt[, .(model = lapply(.SD$date, function(i) run_lm(value1 ~ value2, data = .SD[date %between% (i + c(1L, 5L))]))), by = "variable"][["model"]]
```

Comment: hi @ekoam , thanks this work. However, i want to do one additional thing, for each "variable" itself i want to run multiple iterations for different dates using %between% in data table

for eg. for one each variable i want to subset data further run regression based on below data where i is ranging from 1 to length of date for each variable.

test_dt[date %between% c(as.Date(test_dt$date[i]) + 1, as.Date(test_dt$date[i]) + 3)] 

Can you please suggest how to incorporate this in the solution you suggested

Comment: @JalajPathak Hi, if you look for something other than your original post, please __update your question__ and provide a concrete example of your expected output.

Comment: Hi  @ekoam, i updated the question, please do respond if you have some solution in mind

Comment: hi @ekoam,any way to control for NA values in this , getting the below error:





Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  0 (non-NA) cases